# Best option for modal popup window in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, modal-dialog

This question was asked a few years ago, so I'm going to ask it again.

I'm looking for the best/cleanest option to display a modal popup window upon the click event of an ASP Button control. The contents of the window will be an aspx page.

Cross-browser compatibility is a requirement

jquery/plugins aren't out of the question if they fit the mold.

Comment: A small but important distinction - there is no such thing as a cross-browser modal popup WINDOW. Only IE supports the concept of an entirely new instance of the browser blocking another entire instance of the browser (thank goodness). In IE, ShowModalDialog will prevent the user from interacting with any of the tabs, not just the one that invoked it. If it's going to be cross-browser, it's either not modal, or it's really just a DIV on the page that looks like a "window".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a host of options in the jQuery field:

jQueryUI's [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Wijmo's [Dialog](http://wijmo.com/widgets/wijmo-open/dialog/)

[SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

These are just three options out of many.  jQueryUI is pretty easy to use out of the box, but isn't as customizable (or easy to) and "pretty" as SimpleModal.  At their core, their pretty much all very similar.

If you'd already using jQuery, jQueryUI's option may be a good fit.  Wijmo is also jQueryUI compatible/friendly (use the same theme CSS class names and patterns), so it's also a good fit.

So it kind of depends on what you want.  Something very simple - maybe jQueryUI.  Flashy/pretty -- SimpleModal.  More complex but jQueryUI-friendly - Wijmo.

Comment: All 3 of those links appear to go to the same place.

Comment: Oops -- copy & paste error.  Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I have had no problems with the ModalPopupExtender in the AjaxControlToolkit, which will do exactly what you are intending.

The sample site for the modal popup is  at http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx

Note that the tool kit is free, and that it extends the base ASP.Net controls.

Comment: Also note, that it plugs in very quickly right out of the "box" and contains several other controls

Comment: The hyperlink URL is no longer correct.

Comment: You can find it [here](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[Lightbox Gone Wild](http://particletree.com/features/lightbox-gone-wild/) is insanely quick to integrate, the contents can also be an aspx page.