# Pop-up window while creating a webpage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and i'm creating a website using C#.
I'm opening a pop-up when user clicks a button.

Now i want to perform the task mentioned below:

- When a pop-up opens i do not want user to click anywhere else. I mean
  he should be able to click or do any activity in the pop-up window
  ONLY, whereas he shouldn't be able to do anything in the parent
  window until and unless he closes the pop-up.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Out of close votes, but this a duplicate of [Best option for modal popup window in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6987875/464709).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you are creating the website.  C# is the server-side language and can be used in ASP.Net websites as well as MVC.

If ASP.Net, Ajax Control Toolkit has a modal popup:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx

If MVC, jQuery has a modal popup:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/