# Open Silverlight page as modal/dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, webforms, modal-dialog

How do i open a Silverlight page within a WebForms page ? I want to click on a button on my page which will open a Silverlight form as a dialog.

Comment: You would want to open another page, like any dialog, in another tab/window. This page would contain your Silverlight application.

Comment: @Steve .. thank you for responding, opening a new tab will not give the effect of a popup/modal/dialog over a current page or will it ?

Comment: What your asking to do has nothing to do with Silverlight. You should search for your answer using javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987875/best-option-for-modal-popup-window-in-asp-net