# Bootstrap modal with OnClick button not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

Good day!

I have a **GridView** in Asp.Net wherein if the user click an `<a>` tag, it will launch a modal containing the value of the selected Grid Row. The code uses a javascript command to retrieve the data then distribute it to the designated modal.

The thing is, the `filename` is passed to the modal textbox which is hidden. Now inside the modal is a `OnClick` command button wherein if clicked, should trigger the command.

I have tried it and it is functioning well however when I add the other modal(mainly for adding purposes), the command on the button doesn't work anymore.If I try to remove the other modal, the command now works. I am getting confused as to why this happens?

**GridView Button**

```
<a data-id="<%#Eval("Id") %>"  title="Delete User" class="open-DeleteDialog btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeleteUser">Delete</a>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".open-DeleteDialog").click(function () {
            document.getElementById("<%=IdVal.ClientID%>").value = $(this).data('id');
            $("#DeleteUser").modal("show");

        });
    });
</script>
```

**First Modal**

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="DeleteUser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle1" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">

       <!-- Modal Head -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle1">Modal title</h5>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal Body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-horizontal">
         <h2>Are you sure you want to delete this user?</h2>
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="IdVal" CssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>      
      </div><!--End tag of Modal Body -->

      <!-- Modal Footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Delete1User_Click" onServerClick="Delete1User_Click" Text="Delete User" CssClass="btn btn-Success" />
      </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**Other Modal - one that conflicts with the needed modal**

```
    <!-- Add Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="AddUser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">

       <!-- Modal Head -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal Body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
      Some code here
    </div>      
    </div><!--End tag of Modal Body -->

      <!-- Modal Footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="CreateUser_Click" Text="Add User" CssClass="btn btn-Success" />
      </div>


  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**Code behind of first modal**

```
protected void DeleteUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_deleteuser", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserId", bookId1.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();

            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
```

**Code behind of conflicting modal**

```
protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Some code here
}
```

Why is there a conflict happening in the modal wherein my Delete button command doesn't work yet still clickable? Aside from that, even if I add a bootstrap class to my button, it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Modal Dialogs do not really "work" for Web Applications. The closest equivalent I can think off would be oppening another Browser Window/register card and that one is full of dangers. | Any chance you could do without that thing?

Comment: @Christopher Sir what is the best way to do a Basic crud using modal and gridview? I have been trying at first the Asp:LinkButton but still unsuccessful at launching it

Comment: I found an older answer on the Thematic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987875/best-option-for-modal-popup-window-in-asp-net | But it bears repeating: Modal Dialogs in WebApplications do not work like in Desktop Technology. In WindowsForms, "Modal Dialogs" are a normal Form that was opened with ShowDialog(). Opening that "link" in a new Browser Window/register card would be the only thing I can think off.

Comment: @Christopher I have seen the link. It is somewhat same logic with the code that I have above, the only downside with mine is that the OnClick event is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I was able to solve the problem with the help of the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569857/asp-net-button-onclick-event-not-firing). Since I have another modal with the a `ControlToValidate` in it, what happens is that the other modal values are validated and since it has no value inside, nothings happens. I was able to bypass this by adding this code: `CausesValidation="False"`

```
<asp:Button Id="btnDeleteUser" runat="server" Text="Delete User" OnClick="DeleteUser_Click"  CssClass="btn btn-Success" CausesValidation="False" />
```